# How do you use consistent hashing with the java elasticache libs?

Tags: java, amazon-elasticache, consistent-hashing

Im trying to use elasticache as a memcache service with AWS's elasticache client library for java.

The following code works for connecting to the cluster:

```
_client = new MemcachedClient(_serverList);
```

But any attempt I've made to use consistent hashing results in memcache client failing to initialize:

```
_client = new MemcachedClient(new KetamaConnectionFactory(), _serverList);
```

or

```
ConnectionFactoryBuilder connectionFactoryBuilder = new ConnectionFactoryBuilder();
connectionFactoryBuilder.setLocatorType(Locator.CONSISTENT);
connectionFactoryBuilder.setHashAlg(DefaultHashAlgorithm.KETAMA_HASH);
connectionFactoryBuilder.setClientMode(ClientMode.Dynamic);
ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = connectionFactoryBuilder.build();
_client = new MemcachedClient(connectionFactory, _serverList);
```

Any attempt I've made to use anything but a vanilla MemcacheClient results in errors such as :

> 2015-04-07 07:00:32.914 WARN net.spy.memcached.ConfigurationPoller:  The configuration is null in the server localhost
>   2015-04-07 07:00:32.914 WARN net.spy.memcached.ConfigurationPoller:  Number of consecutive poller errors is 7. Number of minutes since the last successful polling is 0

Also, I've verified with telnet, spymecached libs, and the vanilla MemcacheClient constructor, that the security groups are permissive.

Answer (score 3):

When using the AWS Client Library `KetamaConnectionFactory` defaults to the "dynamic" client mode which tries to poll the list of available memcached nodes from the configuration endpoint.  For this to work your `_serverList` should only contain the configuration endpoint.

Your error message indicates the host was a "plain" memcached node which doesn't understand the ElastiCache extensions.  If this is what you intend to do (specify the nodes yourself rather than use the autodiscovery feature) then you need to use the multiple-arg `KetamaConnectionFactory` constructor and pass in `ClientMode.Static` as the first argument.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use the AddrUtil.getAddresses() method.

```
_client = new MemcachedClient(new KetamaConnectionFactory(), AddrUtil.getAddresses("configEndpoint:port"));
```

or

```
ConnectionFactoryBuilder connectionFactoryBuilder = new ConnectionFactoryBuilder(new KetamaConnectionFactory());
// set any other properties you want on the builder
ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = connectionFactoryBuilder.build();
_client = new MemcachedClient(connectionFactory, AddrUtil.getAddresses("configEndpoint:port"));
```

Comment: I should have included the type for _serverList, List<InetSocketAddress>, which is the same thing AddrUtils is returning.